# Как получить результат загрузки файла

Tags: c#

```
download("http://mysite.ru/download/msuic.mp3", @"C:\Users\Public\Music");
download("http://mysite.ru/download/rofl.txt", @"C:\ProgramData");
if(File.Exists(@"C:\ProgramData\rofl.txt"))
{
    Process.Start(path);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("21w12e");
}
```

Файл с музыкой просто не успевает скачаться и компилятор сразу переходит к следующему действию. Как можно решить эту проблему?

**UPD:**

Функция `download()`:

```
void download(string link,string way) 
{ 
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
    { 
        wc.DownloadFileAsync( 
            // Param1 = Link of file new Uri(adress), 
            // Param2 = Path to save path ); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: забыл,download-это метод void download(string link,string way)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(
                    // Param1 = Link of file
                    new Uri(adress),
                   // Param2 = Path to save
                   path
                );
            }
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем вы используете асинхронный метод в синхронном коде? У `WebClient` есть синхронный метод `DownloadFile`, используйте его и всё будет хорошо.
В принципе, возможность использовать асинхронные методы в синхронном коде есть, но в вашем случае в этом нет никакого смысла.

```
void download(string link,string way) 
{ 
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
    { 
        wc.DownloadFile( 
            // Param1 = Link of file new Uri(adress), 
            // Param2 = Path to save path ); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!